# Unexpected `Specified cast is not valid.` exception (Linq)

Tags: c#, linq

Does anyone knows why I can't cast an `Int` to an `UInt` by using the Linq extension method `Cast<>()`?

```
var myIntList = new List<int>();

myIntList.Add(1);
myIntList.Add(2);
myIntList.Add(3);

var myUIntList = myIntList.Cast<uint>().ToList();
```

It throws a **Specified cast is not valid**. When I'm using a `Select()`, it will work *(ofcourse)*.

```
var myIntList = new List<int>();

myIntList.Add(1);
myIntList.Add(2);
myIntList.Add(3);

var myUIntList = myIntList.Select(i => (uint)i).ToList();
```

*(is it a bug or not implemented feature?)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) is implemented as an extension method on `IEnumerable` (the *non-generic* interface).

This implication of this is that the values in the sequence are cast from `object`, which means boxing and unboxing is involved for value types.  You can only unbox to the exact type.  For example:

```
int i = 1;
object boxed = i;

int unboxToInt = (int)boxed; // ok
uint unboxToUint = (uint)boxed; // invalid cast exception
```

You can read more about boxing [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

Comment: That makes it all clear. I'll do some reading.